# Angular - disable another control based on no value entered in a textbox

Tags: angular

I am using Angular and the FormBuilder to generate the FormGroup.
I want to be able to disable the status control if there is no value entered in the legacyId text box.

I was hoping the below would work, but the formGroup I am referencing on the status line is not yet created, its calling its own formGroup. How would I be able to do this so that the status gets disabled if the textbox is empty?

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    legacyId: [{value: this.myItems.legacyId : ''), [Validators.maxLength(this.legacyIdMaxLength)]],
    status: [{value: this.statuses.find(x => x.id === status), disabled: this.formGroup.value.legacyId === ''}, [Validators.required]],
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try with `valueChanges` like :

```js
this.formGroup.get('legacyId').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (!!value) {
    this.formGroup.get('status').disable();
  } else {
    this.formGroup.get('status').enable();
  }
  this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that seems to work, had to wrap the enable in an else, but that seems to work

Comment: I've updated my code so people in the futur could find the solution quickly ;)